# androidstudio help, how can i compare the deviceID stored from firebase with the url link from qrcode generated in android studio, I always get null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

these are my codes, I always get null with the storedDeviceID, when it should be getting the device id from the firebase.

I already edited the code :) I also put some breakpoints as you said, and it was hit on the val storedDeviceID, where I set the first breakpoint.

```
private fun retrieveLatestData() {
    val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("payments")
        .orderByChild("order_id")
        .limitToLast(1)
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            val storedDeviceID = dataSnapshot.child("deviceID").getValue(String::class.java)
            val outputData = dataSnapshot.child("amount_paid").getValue(String::class.java)
            val amount = outputData?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
            dialogOnStartup = false
            Log.d("DataSnapshot", dataSnapshot.toString())
            Log.d("DeviceIDComparison", "storedDeviceID: $storedDeviceID")
            try {
                if (storedDeviceID != null && storedDeviceID == deviceID) {
                    if (dialogOnStartup) {
                        dialogOnStartup = false
                    } else {
                        showPaymentDialog(amount)
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("DeviceIDComparison", "Device IDs do not match")
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Device IDs do not match: $deviceID and $storedDeviceID",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); 
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Step 1 is to stop ignoring potential errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be: `override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Once you've done that, put the updated code into your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. And then put a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange` and in `onCancelled` and run the code in the debugger. When doing this, which of the breakpoints (if any) does it hit?

Comment: I also put some breakpoints as you said, and it was hit on the val storedDeviceID, where I set the first breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code in the `onDataChange` method needs to handle that list by looping over `dataSnapshot.children`. My Kotlin is not fluent, but it should be something like this:

```
val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("payments")
    .orderByChild("order_id")
    .limitToLast(1)
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (result in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val storedDeviceID = result.child("deviceID").getValue(String::class.java)
            val outputData = result.child("amount_paid").getValue(String::class.java)
            ...
```